# Loop in a switch case statement

Tags: c++

I need help with validating a switch case statement i need it to check what the user has entered and if it does not match reject it and tell them to do it again. the one i have at the moment partially works but will reject the first number then break when trying to enter another number. Help  If you need to see the whole program just ask.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
#include "cmath"


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


float ALT0();
float ALT5000();
float ALT10000();
float ALT15000();
float ALT20000();
float ALT25000();
float ALT30000();
float ALT35000();
float ALT40000();
void an_answer(float a);

char Restart;
char op;
float answer;

do
{
cout << "\n\t\t\tOperational Flight Plan\n" << endl;

cout << "For the saftey of everyone on board, there will be 100 kg added to the overall\namount to give the aircraft more fuel incase of a head on wind or delays at the landing airport.\n" << endl;
cout << "Select Altitude the aircraft will fly at: " << endl;
cout << "0 for 0ft\n1 for 5000ft\n2 for 10000ft\n3 for 15000ft\n4 for 20000ft\n5 for 25000ft\n6 for 30000ft\n7 for 35000ft\n8 for 40000ft" << endl;
cin >> op;
switch (op)
{
case'0':
    answer=ALT0();
    break;

case '1':
    answer=ALT5000();
    break;

case '2':
    answer=ALT10000();
    break;

case '3':
    answer=ALT15000();
    break;

case '4':
    answer=ALT20000();
    break;

case '5':
    answer=ALT25000();
    break;

case '6':
    answer=ALT30000();
    break;

case '7':
    answer=ALT35000();
    break;

case '8':
    answer=ALT40000();
    break;
    default:
        cout << "You must enter a number from 0-8" << endl;
        cin >> op;

    break;

}

an_answer(answer);

cout << "Do you want to do another calculation? Press Y for yes and anything else to quit.";
cin >> Restart;
} while (Restart=='y' || Restart=='Y');

//system("PAUSE");
//return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You have potential [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code: If the user enter anything but a letter then `Restart` will not be modified and since it's not initialized you will then check the (indeterminate) value of the uninitialized variable, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: You should also have a `default` case in the `switch`, what if the user enters anything invalid?

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you're hitting enter after entering the number. Your first `cin >> op` reads the number, but your second one reads the enter key. If you want to read in an entire line, use a function that reads in an entire line.

Alternately, move the second `cin >> op` up to before the `switch` statement. This will break if someone enters more than one character before hitting enter but will work otherwise.